# What things does ZFC not know if it knows?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, proof-theory, metamathematics, independence-results

The statement "ZFC $\vdash 0=1$" is independent of ZFC due to Goedel's second incompleteness theorem. That got me wondering, for what other statements $\phi$ is "ZFC $\vdash \phi$" independent of ZFC?

Now of course, for any statement $\phi$ for which "ZFC $\nvdash \phi$" is true, then "ZFC $\vdash \phi$" is independent of ZFC. So instead, **I'll ask which "ZFC $\vdash \phi$" are independent of ZFC + Con(ZFC), and stronger theories?**

(Of course, easy examples are Con(T) for T=ZFC+Con(ZFC) or stronger theory, but are there others?)

Comment: Independent does not mean "unprovable" but "neither provable nor disprovable".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm aware. Does something in my question suggest that I meant unprovable?

Comment: Read the first sentence of the second paragraph. It literally says that you mean "unprovable".

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean? If ZFC $\vdash \lnot \phi$, then $ZFC \vdash \phi$ is equivalent to $\lnot$ Con(ZFC), which is independent of ZFC.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It would be advisable to use quote marks or something like that to make sure that "$\sf ZFC\Vdash\lnot\phi$" is read as a statement *in arithmetic* rather than a part of the sentence.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I see the confusion. Yeah, I added quote marks then.

Comment: Yeah, now it's much better. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should say instead: if $\text{ZFC}\not\vdash\phi$ is consistent with ZFC (rather than $\text{ZFC}\vdash\neg\phi$ is true), then "$\text{ZFC}\vdash\phi$" is independent. Otherwise, there is a missing consistency assumption.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I was taking for granted that ZFC was consistient, but fair enough.

Comment: But that isn't enough, since knowing $\text{ZFC}\vdash\neg\phi$ plus $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is not generally enough to know that $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC}+\text{ZFC}\not\vdash\phi)$, which is what you need for independence.

Comment: You edited to say "$\text{ZFC}\not\vdash\phi$ is true", but I think it should say, "$\text{ZFC}\not\vdash\phi$ is consistent with $\text{ZFC}$."

Comment: And also, now you are asking for independence over $\text{ZFC}+\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$, rather than merely independence over $\text{ZFC}$. These are not the same thing, and that change affects everything I have said so far.

Comment: Of course, no statement is independent over $\text{ZFC}$ "and stronger theories", since if we add the statement to the theory, it becomes settled and therefore no longer independent. You question seems to be a moving target.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I was asking about that the whole time, actually. Sorry if I suggested otherwise.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It shouldn't be interpreted as"statements independent of (ZFC + Con(ZFC) and stronger theories) but as "statements independent of (ZFC + Con(ZFC)) and statements independent of (stronger theories)". Each theory gives a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to use "independent of $T$" to mean "unprovable in $T$", so I'll  interpret the question that way (not as "neither provable nor refutable in $T$).

If $ZF\vdash\phi$ is true, then it can be proved in ZF and in fact in much weaker systems, just by taking a proof of $\phi$ in ZF and verifying that it is indeed a proof (and ends with $\phi$). Conversely, if $ZF\vdash\phi$ is false, then it can't be proved in ZF or in ZF + Con(ZF) or in any arithmetically sound theory. (My Platonism is showing here, as I take it for granted that ZF + Con(ZF) is arithmetically sound because it's true.) So $ZF\vdash\phi$ is unprovable in ZF + Con(ZF) iff it is false, i.e., if $\phi$ is unprovable in ZF.

Comment: I actually did intend for independence to be "neither provable nor refutable in $T$". For example, assuming that $ZFC$ is consistient, then ZFC $\vdash 0=1$ is neither provable nor refutable from ZFC. Its obvious that if $ZFC \vdash \phi$ is true, then even PA can prove that fact. I guess I'm more interested in when $ZFC \nvdash \phi$ is true, but not provable in strong theories.

Comment: @PyRulez: What does it mean "true"? True ***where***?

Comment: @AsafKaragila true in true arithmetic, I suppose.

Comment: @PyRulez: How do you what is true in true arithmetic? Is Con(ZFC) true? Is Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)) true? is Con(ZFC+there is a measurable cardinal) true? Is Con(ZF+DC+AD) true? I can continue for more or less forever with these questions (and for each answer I would probably ask a follow up of "Why? How do you know that?"), at some point you're going to have to give me a better answer than just "true in true arithmetic".

Comment: When I say ZFC $\nvdash \phi$, I mean there is no $c$ which the goedel code of a proof of $\phi$ from the axioms of $ZFC$.

You would have to analyze that question in whatever meta-theory your using. You could use PA, if that suits your fancy (although you probably wouldn't get very far).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not see why anything more is needed. An arithmetic statement is true if it holds in the standard model, that is the standard interpretation of the term. Maybe I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Andrés: Okay, so tell me please, is Con(ZFC+supercompact cardinals exist) is true?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course.

Comment: @Andrés: Okay, what about Con(ZF+there is a super-Berkeley cardinal)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not know the definition of the term, I'm afraid. I suspect Berkeley cardinals and several strengthenings are consistent, but I am not certain. Anyway, the question of what I think I doubt is particularly interesting. Perhaps what you are pursuing is a semi-formal explanation of those beliefs, accompanied by a semi-formal theory that allows us to verify that they are correct?

Comment: @Andrés: I thought about a super-Reinhardt and about a Berkeley, but mixed them together. In either case, my point is that "true in true arithmetic" is something which depends a lot on the universe, or the person interpreting the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, obviously. Naturally, I do not *know* that many obvious things are "true of the true natural numbers" in the sense that I do not have formal proofs of them in very weak axiom systems, and I do not even have a coherent semi-formal definition of "true natural numbers". Your question about supercompacts was asked provocatively, or so it seemed to me, so I answered accordingly. The actual answer is that I *think* it is true, modulo standard caveats (such as "what do I mean?"), but cannot prove it in a system that would allow all interested players to agree in the answer.

Comment: Hey, logicians: what do you even mean when you say "true arithmetic", "true natural numbers" etc? :) As far as I know, there are only formal theories, etc etc.. Or are you holding Platonist beliefs?

Comment: @Qfwfq It tends to be at least somewhat Platonist. Of course we can embed the whole thing in an appropriate theory, but the default language is certainly Platonistic; and I think many (most?) mathematicians feel that natural numbers (and the set of natural numbers) "exist" in some sense.

Comment: I agree with @NoahSchweber's last comment about Platonism, and I'd add that, when I say that an arithmetical statement is true, I mean exactly what most mathematicians who are not logicians mean by that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: when I say an arithmetical statement is "true" (without any further comments) I usually mean that some specified standard theory, strong enough to be used as foundation of mathematics (e.g. ZFC), proves that statement from its axioms. If I were referring to a certain theory of arithmetic like PA I would say e.g. "the statement is true in PA" meaning that it is provable from the axioms of PA. In any case I would not base my assertions on some metaphysical Platonist belief. I think this is what most non-logicians do. Or not?

Comment: @Qfwfq: I would say it is not. Most non-logician mathematicians have an even firmer sense of the natural numbers "as a structure", and when they say "true" they mean "true in that structure".  At the same time few know much of anything about formal logic. // Separately, phrases such as "true in PA" are somewhat painful to read, even if I know what is meant, because they mix truth with provability in a way that the two should not mix.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: ok, I see. But "true" has no meaning if not "provable in some (meta- or otherwise) theory". Even "the natural numbers as a structure" is a just a way of saying, when what is really meant is: "it's a theorem of ZFC that blah blah". I guess Platonism will never make much sense to me (philosophically speaking).

Comment: @Qfwfq My dictionary lists quite a few meanings of "true", none of which are "provable in some (meta- or otherwise) theory". The first of those is "in accordance with fact or reality", and that's the meaning I had in mind. Some philosophies either expel "fact or reality" from mathematics or conflate these with "what we know" or "what we could know"; others regard this as unwarranted chutzpah about our cognitive abilities.

Comment: Nah. For me, let Platonism die! (intended as in E.B. Davies, https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/newsletter/pdf/2007-06-64.pdf)

Comment: @Qfwfq I recommend reading section 10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.05641.pdf.

Comment: @user76284: yes, I am basically "Stefan". I don't agree with the last part of that section. First, there's probably a huge difference between a theory of syntax for strings of symbols and arithmetic, as the latter needs some kind of induction principle that immediately catapults you outside the realm of finiteness; and the "most meta" metatheory will always be informal, but only dealing will silly unproblematic activities such  as pushing symbols around (without asserting anything about them). Second, I don't *need* to prove (Hilbert program style) that PA is consistent: I just *use* PA; (...)

Comment: (...) and I don't *assert* a certain string of symbols resulting from a formal proof: I just *point to* it. Finally, I think truth (in the higher, metaphysical, sense) is overrated: we don't need it in mathematical practice; all we do (in principle, obviously) is proving things rigorously (i.e. formally) from hypotheses. And the belief that a certain string of symbols is "true" (in an absolute sense) is a human disposition of mind, based on psychology, not a mathematical fact.

Comment: @user76284: A slogan could be: we know the rules of chess, we can play chess, we don't need to bother about "what chess pieces really are".

Comment: @Qfwfq Do you agree with Timothy Chow's assertion that you, as Stefan, cannot know the syntactic fact that, beginning with the symbol 0 and repeatedly prepending the symbol S, you will never obtain a string that contains the symbol $\land$? The reason I ask is that this fact seems to be a typical application of mathematical induction, whose availability in arithmetic you cite as a distinction between arithmetic and syntax theory.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: The answer I'm inclined to give right now probably is: who cares? I append the $S$ and... look, there's no $\wedge$! The whole point, I think, is pushing the ontological baggage about truth and existence out of mathematics and into, say, the philosophy of language. So there's a philosophical question right there: "what symbols *really* are, and how do they *really* behave?" (like "are they pieces of ink on paper, or equivalence classes of such, and do such equivalence classes *really* exist..." and on and on and on), but it's not mathematicians' business to investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking what happens if you iterate adding consistency statements.  There's a whole book about that, "Inexhaustibility" by Torkel Franzen, though it starts with arithmetic rather than ZFC.  This article is also good:

https://xorshammer.com/2009/03/23/what-happens-when-you-iterate-godels-theorem/